# "https" module not found in node

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to import the "https" module in node but I keep getting the *Cannot find module 'https'* error.

I tried using both

```
import https from "https"
```

and

```
const https = require("https")
```

but the result is the same. My understanding is that https is a core module in node so does not need to be installed separately and this is the first time I am getting this error. Any idea what might be causing it or how to get around it?

Comment: you can try reinstalling node